# How to integrate $\int_0^N \frac{\vert \sin(x) \vert}{x} dx$

Tags: integration

Let $N$ be a strictly positive integer.
How to integrate $\int_0^N \frac{\vert \sin(x) \vert}{x} \ \mathrm{d}x$ ?
I tried to subdivise $[0,N]$ in distincts intervals but couldn't achieve a proper resolution of the integral.

I have to show that the limit when N tend to $\infty$ is $\infty$ , so I would also accept an answer that could permit to show it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider that $\int_0^{\pi} \sin x \,dx = 2$ and use this result to conclude
$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{|\sin x|}{x}\,dx \geq \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \sin x\,dx = \frac{2}{\pi}.$$
Now show that similarly
$$\int_{(k-1)\pi}^{k\pi}\frac{|\sin x|}{x}\,dx \geq \frac{2}{k\pi}, \quad k \in \mathbb N \setminus \{0\},$$
so that
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{|\sin x|}{x}\,dx = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{(k-1)\pi}^{k\pi} \frac{|\sin x|}{x}\,dx \geq \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k} = \infty.$$

Comment: Very clear answer to me.